# Is the pullback of an ample divisor always nef?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I have read that if $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of projective varieties and $D$ is an ample Cartier divisor on $Y$ then $f^*D$ is nef.  The proof is that ample implies semi-ample, which means that some multiple is base-point free.  This implies that some multiple of the pullback is also base-point free which implies nef-ness of $f^*D$.

My confusion is over two things - first, where is the projective hypothesis used in this argument?  Second, I don't really understand how the pullback of $D$ is defined when $f$ is arbitrary, so I don't really understand how we know that the pullback of a base-point free divisor is base-point free.

If $f$ is flat then we can pullback $D$ by just taking it's inverse image, which will be a Cartier divisor.  In this case it seems clear that the pullback of a base-point free divisor would be base-point free, and this does not seem to use the projective assumption unless I am mistaken.  So it seems to me that the pullback of an ample divisor by a flat morphism is nef, even without the projective assumption.  Is this correct?

Comment: What does nef mean for a non-projective variety? In most defintions, a Cartier divisor $D$ (or equivalently, a line bundle $L$) is nef, if $D\cdot C\geq 0$ for all curves. Intersection number is meaningless for non-projective varieties. Similarly, pulling back in the above set-up should be thought of as pulling back the corresponding line bundle, which always make sense.

Comment: Well, isn't $f$ proper since $X$ and $Y$ are complete by Stacks, Tag [01W6](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01W6)? The other place where you use projectivity is when you talk about nef divisors on $X$, as @Mohan points out. The only way you can get rid of a projectivity assumption is then on $Y$, but that case is not interesting since the image of $X$ in $Y$ would then be a single point.

Comment: @Mohan maybe it isn't defined and I am just confused.  I need to learn intersection theory.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama thank you for that link.  Does $f$ begin proper help to pullback divisors?  Is this used to show that the pullback of semi-ample is semi-ample?

Comment: @Seth You can use the projection formula [Fulton, Prop. 2.5(c)]: if $f \colon X \to Y$ is proper, and $D$ is your Cartier divisor, then $f_*(c_1(f^*D) \cap \alpha) = c_1(D) \cap f_*(\alpha)$ to compute intersections: $\int_X c_1(f^*D) \cap \alpha = \int_Y c_1(D) \cap f_*(\alpha)$. For what it means to pullback Cartier divisors, see [this answer on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/a/18426/33088) and Ch. 2 in Fulton.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama Thank you.

Comment: @Mohan Lazarsfeld defines intersection product between proper varieties doesn't he ?